# SQL Server: explode BOM by joining table with itself to get youngest child

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, erp

I want to fully explode a BOM table using SQL Server. The table is in a regular Microsoft SQL Server database. Suppose I have a table like this:

[image]

I am looking for a way to explode this so that it lists every component for every BOM in the BOM column. The resulting table would look as follows:

[image]

Note that total quantity column should aggregate properly. There is no predetermined limit on how deep the hierarchy can go.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server supports recursive CTEs, so you can do:

```
with t as (
      select v.*
      from (values ('A', 'C', 2), ('C', 'F', 3), ('A', 'B', 1)) v(bom, component, quantity)
     ),
     cte as (
      select bom as source, bom, component, quantity
      from t
       union all
      select cte.source, t.bom, t.component, cte.quantity * t.quantity
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.component = t.bom
     )
select *
from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3f1c188c7b2c117c308e2b34e11990b6) is a db<>fiddle.